# How to compare values from TempData?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

i am sending two values from controller,saved in TempData.but unable to compare them in my view because of some syntax error. 
**code:**

```
<script> 
    @{
        var i = TempData["Book"];
        var j= TempData["Surah"];
     }

   if (@i == "1")
    {
       alert("inside cond.!);
       $('#book_selection').attr("disabled", "disabled");
       $('#book_selection').selectedIndex = 1;
    }
</script>
```

showing syntx error on @i. i have tried `@i.equals("1")` but no difference...

Comment: what does it say `console.log(TempData["Book"]);`. if you could tell us what output is there in the console?

Comment: i've checked it in debug mode, there is no issue in assignment. problem is with comparison and inner statements...

Answer (score 0):

You could safely ignore the syntax errors shown in Visual Studio. Those are bugs in the Razor syntax highlighter. Run your application and it will work fine. Also make sure that you compare the correct types. For example if the value you stored inside `TempData["Book"]` is an integer then your test should be:

```
if (@i == 1) {
    ...    
}
```

This being said the proper way to send data from an action to a view is to use the view model. Not TempData and not ViewData and not ViewBag.

Comment: how can i use view model to store my values , then ?

Comment: Very easy. From what I can see in your question you have 2 values: `Book` and `Surah`. So you will add 2 properties to your view model of the corresponding type. And then inside the controller action you will populate them from their original source (`TempData` in this case).